# What is needed to develop an ArcGIS application? (C#?)

Tags: arcgis

I am trying to fully understand the genius that is ArcGIS.

I want to develop a piece of software that uses the engine.  This application needs to import user data (GeoTIFF, etc) and allow users to put points and polygons on a map. I would think this would be VERY straightforward.

I am unable to find sufficient detail on how to begin this process and was hoping someone here could help me.

There are APIs, there is the ArcEngine, there is ArcObjects, also SDKS.  I don't know which I need to develop my application.  I would love to make a Windows Form application in C#.

What would I need?  ArcEngine?  I am working on computers that have ArcGIS desktop installed.  How can I know what else is installed (Engine, Objects, etc...)?  How can I get ArcEngine if that is what I need?

Thank you.

Comment: If you don't have any luck here, try asking this on http://gis.stackexchange.com.  It's a StackExchange site speacialising in GIS Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would love to make a Windows Form application in C#.

To develop such an application you will need an ArcGIS Engine license in order to use the SDK. ArcEngine (aka. ArcObjects, when you're talking about .Net) is basically the guts of ArcGIS without the pretty (and complicated) interface. You can buy a license for ArcEngine via [EDN](http://edn.esri.com/). Note that this gives you the ability to develop (and run) applications yourself - for other people to run them they need EITHER an ArcEngine or ArcGIS Desktop license, and then it gets a bit complicated depending on what you want your application to do - some tasks may require higher license levels.

If your users already have ArcGIS Desktop installed with the licensing sorted out (either floating or stand-alone) then your application can use that license, they don't need to install anything else.

ESRI are pretty coy about EDN pricing on their website, but I think it used to be about USD $1500/year (per seat?) for basic access? (happy to be wrong about this)